# iOS: Timer app in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, timer

A lot of people when creating a Timer app or a StopWatch, or similar uses this function:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
```

in order to update the timer using a user defined function `updateTimer` that gets called every `timeInterval`.

But my question is whether using such function could give a **non** accurate timer, since we call a function that is user defined and we don't count the overheads that there may be, because of our implementation. And if we have loops or other stuff going on, am I right that this isn't the best approach?

I'm wondering because in my case I would need to use this function to increment a variable timer, and also another function that computes the string of the timer to display every time the `updateTimer` gets called.

What would be the better and most accurate approach to implement a timer? Maybe using NSDate?

Comment: Yes.  `Timer` is not accurate.  It is better to record a start time `let start = Date()` and have an update interval of `0.1` and compute the interval with `let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)` in the `updateTimer` routine.  That will avoid drift in the timer since you'll always be calculating the actual interval.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks I like that idea.. but why update the interval every 0.1? And also your idea is to display the variable `interval` right?

Comment: Yes. Display the variable interval. The reason do to it 10 times a second is so that your are never more than 1/10th of a second late in updating the display value.  If you use a timeInterval of `1` and the computed interval is `22.999` you'd display `22`.  One second later the interval might be `24.000` and you'd display `24`.  Your displayed value would jump by 2 seconds.  Updating the display 10 times a second means you could never be early/late by more than `0.1` second which would hardly be noticeable.

Comment: Thanks, then I understood your idea correctly! But now I’m thinking how this could impact the performance of the app. Is it negligible, or could it slow down if the function does several tasks?

Comment: I expect it’s negligeable. If you’re doing a lot of extra work every second, compute the new label and only update it if is has changed and only do the extra work if it has changed.